# Reorder a string using REGEXP_REPLACE in a Redshift table

Tags: sql, regex, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, regexp-replace

I am trying to replace a pattern in a Redshift table using regular expression. I have been trying with `REGEXP_RELACE` but no success so far.

My data, with columns name `sequence` and varchar data type, looks like:

```
1420311 > 1380566 > 1380566 > 9991380564  
1489773 > 9991489773  
1367309 > 1367309 > 9991367309
```

I would like to use `REGEXP_RELACE` (or any other function) in SQL Redshift to get the following result:

```
1420311 > 1380566 > 1380566 > 1380564 > 999
1489773 > 1489773 > 999
1367309 > 1367309 > 1367309 > 999
```

So that is finding the 999 sequence when it appears at the start of the string, and putting it last preceded by a `>` and maintain the remaining string.

Greatly appreciate any help!

Comment: I think you may have a typo in the second line of your expected output.

Comment: Do you want the 999 follow the sequence member it was found in (which in your sample input happens to always be at the end) or do you want it at the very end (in case the 999 is e.g. found in the very first sequence member, which is not among your samples)?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Do you want a query showing the result or do you want the database content be updated? (Good question, @TimBiegeleisen.)

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution (based on Tims), which will additionally

- update the database content,
  `UPDATE yourTable SET sequence = ...` instead od `SELECT ... FROM yourTable`
- find the "999" at the start of any member and tolerate whitespace before newline,
  no `$`
- move it to the very end of the sequence,
  using `( > [0-9]{7}){0,}` inside the 2nd capture group
- find any leading group of digits breaking the 7digit rule, not only "999",
  using `([0-9]{1,})` instead of "999" and capturing it

Code:

```
UPDATE yourTable SET sequence =
    REGEXP_REPLACE(sequence, '([0-9]{1,})([0-9]{7}( > [0-9]{7}){0,})', '$2 > $1')
```

Comment: Great. I like how you look for any leading group of digits with more than 7 digits.
Answering your question above, yes, '999' is only *expected* in the last member of any sequence. And yes, `UPDATE` will do just fine.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want a query which can generate this output then the following should work:

```
SELECT
    REGEXP_REPLACE(sequence, '999([0-9]{7})$', '$1 > 999')
FROM yourTable
```

Comment: Thanks, great solution. RegExp do my head in!
And, yes, that was a typo.